# Are distance-related paradoxes limited by the size of an atom?

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, infinity, paradoxes

See these 2 paradoxes:

### Coastline paradox

> The coastline paradox is the counterintuitive observation that the coastline of a landmass does not have a well-defined length.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox

### Dichotomy paradox

> Suppose Homer wants to catch a stationary bus. Before he can get there, he must get halfway there. Before he can get halfway there, he must get a quarter of the way there. Before traveling a quarter, he must travel one-eighth; before an eighth, one-sixteenth; and so on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox

## Question

These paradoxes state that we can't measure these distance because as we look at smaller and smaller scales the distance increase to infinity. Are these paradoxes limited by the size of an atom?

Let's suppose that we can see the atoms of the coast:

```
O
OO
OOO
OOOO
    OO
Land OO
    OO             Sea
OOOOO
OO
O
```

Then we can measure the length at the right of the coast, for example by tracing a curve which join each consecutive atom:

```
\
O\
OO\
OOO\
    O\
Land O|
    O/             Sea
OOOO/
O/
/
```

This would make a finite length in theory (even if it would be very hard to measure in practice). Is it relevant to measure the distance under the size of an atom?

If the size of an atom is relevant, then is the [Plank Length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28length%29#Subatomic) the limit?

> according to string theory lengths smaller than this do not make any physical sense

Comment: This isn't math... this is philosophy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a Coastline](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/553194/119611), but this is a different question about the same paradox.

Comment: Even if space is continuous, calculus enables us to measure such recursive lengths. And the Planck length only sets the limit of measurement - it does *not* mean that space is discretised and therefore would not resolve this.

Comment: This seems to me a question about physics, not about mathematics.

Comment: It is not a question on which physics has anything to say because physics has yet to establish whether space is discrete or continuous. And mathematicians have no problem with infinite series. So it's just philosophers who are concerned with this question - I suppose they have to fill their days somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coastline paradox is a way to illustrate fractals. So it's not intended for the physics world. If you go into the physics world, all the particles in the "perimeter" of a coastline are constantly moving, so an exact answer cannot be given but an upper bound can be found using Plank's length.

The Zeno paradox lies on the assumption that an infinite amount of steps require an infinite amount of time. But that's obviously false. If Homer is walking at a constant speed, then he'll walk half the distance to the bus in $t$ seconds. Then he'll walk half the remaining distance in $t/2$ seconds... at the end, he'll take $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t}{2^k} = 2t$ seconds to get to the bus.

Answering the question in the comment as to what I mean by constanly moving particles I wrote this:

As far as I know all particles have momentum. The warmer they are, the faster they go, and even if you could get a particle at absolute zero (wich can't be done) it has what is called 0-point energy that gives it still some motion. And if you "freeze" the coastline so the particles stop moving, then you would know it's momentum (it would be 0 since they don't move) so by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, you wouldn't know where the particles are, so you couldn't make any measurement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by *constantly moving*? What is the scale of this movement? Can you suppose that we can freeze the coastline so that nothing move?

Comment: As far as I know all particles have momentum. The warmer they are, the faster they go, and even if you could get a particle at absolute zero (wich can't be done) it has what is called 0-point energy that gives it still some motion. And if you "freeze" the coastline so the particles stop moving, then you would know it's momentum (it would be 0 since they don't move) so by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, you wouldn't know where the particles are, so you couldn't make any measurement.

Comment: Correction: then you *would* know its momentum to *infinite* precision, and so by the uncertainty principle...

Comment: @DarthGeek : can you please add the content of your comment to your answer?